# Como utilizar um banco Oracle e um Sql Server simultaneamente com Entity Framework 6 em uma única aplicação?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, oracle

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde as informações serão persistidas em dois bancos de dados, um MS SQL Server e um Oracle.

Não tenho opção de usar os dois bancos no mesmo SGBD, pois o banco Oracle é de outra aplicação e outro servidor sob a qual não tenho controle e o SQL server é o SGBD padrão da nossa empresa.

A aplicação fará inicialmente persistência em uma base de dados MS SQL Server e em um determinado momento do fluxo de utilização precisará persistir algumas informações (não necessariamente as mesmas) no banco Oracle.

É uma aplicação ASP.Net MVC 5 com Entity Framework 6.1.3.

A minha arquitetura está dividida em camadas, seguindo a seguinte estrutura:

```
1. Presentation (Solution folder)  
    |-- Presentation.Web (Projeto Asp.net MVC 5)  
2. Domain (Solution folder)  
    |-- Domain.SqlServer (Projeto class library)  
    |-- Domain.Oracle (Projeto class library)  
3. Infraestructure (Solution folder)  
    |-- Crosscutting (Solution folder)  
        |-- Infraestructure.Crosscutting.IoC (Projeto class library)  
    |-- Data (Solution folder)  
        |-- Infraestructure.Data.SqlServer (Projeto class library)  
        |-- Infraestructure.Data.Oracle (Projeto class library)
```

Todas as referências entre os "assemblies" será criada por um "container" de injeção de dependências, provavelmente usarei "simple injector".

Minha abordagem em relação ao banco Sql Server é "code first" com "Migrations". Para o banco Oracle criarei as classes de entidade, configuração das entidades, contexto e etc manualmente apesar da base já existir.

Segue abaixo como está o web.config da camada de apresentação:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <entityFramework>
    <!--<defaultConnectionFactory type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.OracleConnectionFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" />-->
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="OracleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=Servidor)(PORT=Porta)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=NomeServico)))" />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlServerDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=Servidor; Database=BancoDeDados; Uid=Usuario; Pwd=Senha;" />
    <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=Usuario; Password=Senha; Data Source=OracleDataSource;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Também instalei o "Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013" e tanto na camada de apresentação como na camada de dados Oracle instalei os seguintes pacotes nuget:

- EntityFramework 6.1.3
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 12.1.2400
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 12.1.2400

Enquanto eu não havia iniciado a configuração da parte Oracle a camada de dados Sql Server estava funcionando corretamente. Eu criei todo o modelo e fiz a geração do banco com "Migrations", entretanto após começar a configurar o Oracle não consigo mais atualizar o modelo Sql Server. Sempre que tento adicionar uma nova configuração do modelo com Add-Migration me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> The Entity Framework provider type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.`

Será que alguém já passou por uma situação similar e pode me dar uma dica do que pode estar errado?

Comment: Você está configurando a parte de SQL e Oracle em Context separados né?

Comment: Ola Guilherme. Sim, dois db context separados. Ate separei em dois projetos dadas as diferenças de configuração de diferentes providers. Para aumentar o desacoplamento tbm.

Answer (score 0):

Deleta a tag:

```
<provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

depois verificar se o erro irá persistir.
OBS: faça um backup do arquivo antes.

Comment: Olá Victor, obrigado pela resposta. Nem estou neste projeto mais mas continuo curioso sobre a solução do problema. Na sua sugestão eu tiraria a referência do provider do oracle, mas isso não faria o meu oracle parar de funcionar? Nesse caso específico precisaria dos dois providers sendo utilizados pela mesma aplicação simultaneamente. De todo modo depois vou fazer uma poc para tentar validar sua resposta. Novamente obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: Nos meus projetos eu nunca uso essas tags, pode testar.